# jQuery to Hide Individual Notifications

Tags: jquery

I've been learning jQuery for a few weeks and have come across a task that I can't figure out.

I have been working on a clients admin control panel and have implemented notifications that appear at the top of the page used for various reasons.

What I have managed to do so far is make the div clickable to hide it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click_hide').click(function() {
    $('.click_hide').slideUp('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
  });
});

<ul class="system_messages click_hide">
  <li class="blue"><span class="ico"></span><strong class="system_title">There have been 17 new cases since your last login.</strong></li>
  <li class="blue"><span class="ico"></span><strong class="system_title">There have been 17 new cases since your last login.</strong></li>
</ul>
```

What I would like to be able to do though is be able to hide notifications individually (`<li class="click_hide">...</li>`) and when there are none left the `<ul>...</ul>` disappears to.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Bind the click to the `<li>`s, not the `<ul>`
2. Use `this` within the click handler to refer to the specific `<li>` that was clicked.
3. You probably want to `.remove()` the `<li>`s once they're hidden.
4. Hide the `<ul>` if it doesn't contain any children.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.click_hide > li').click(function() {
    var li = $(this).slideUp('slow', function() {
      // Animation complete
      var ul = $('ul.click_hide');

      // Remove li
      li.remove();

      // Hide ul?
      if (ul.children().length === 0) {
        ul.slideUp('slow', function() {
          // Remove ul
          ul.remove();
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Everything works but the UL doesn't seem to slide up to the top again, or at least the rest of the content doesnt move back up to the top where it was prior to the ul being inserted

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something similar to this? (Pardon any syntax errors - a bit off the cuff)

```
$('.blue').click(function() {
  //Hides the individual notification
  $(this).hide();
    //Hides the ul if no additional notifications are present
    if($('.system_messages').size()  == 0 )
    {
      $('.system_messages').hide(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `click_hide` class is on the list object - so your click handler is actually referencing that. So `this` would refer to the `ul` rather than the `li`.

Firstly, set the click handler for the `li` by selecting `.click_hide li`. Then use `remove()` to remove the element from the DOM and check how many more list items are in the list.

```
$('.click_hide li').click(function() {
    var list = $("ul.system_messages"),
        $this = $(this);

    $this.slideUp('slow', function() {
        $this.remove();
        if (!list.children().length) list.remove();
    });
});
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/tmL7m/

The reason I have `$this = $(this)` is because I want to reference the same jQuery object a few times and this saves having to recreate it. The same goes for the `$list` (prefixing the variables with `$` is just a convention to indicate it's a jQuery object).